# Node JS installation - ECONNRESET issue

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to install Karma from node JS and while trying to install, I get ECONNRESET issue. Please find below the error when I try to run the command "npm install karma --save-dev" in my project folder.

```
D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder>npm install karma --save-dev
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.5
|


> bufferutil@1.2.1 install D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Personal\Personal\Xampp\htdocs\project folder\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
karma@0.13.15 node_modules\karma
├── batch@0.5.3
├── di@0.0.1
├── rimraf@2.4.3
├── graceful-fs@4.1.2
├── mime@1.3.4
├── colors@1.1.2
├── bluebird@2.10.2
├── source-map@0.5.3
├── useragent@2.1.7 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── http-proxy@1.12.0 (eventemitter3@1.1.1, requires-port@0.0.1)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── lodash@3.10.1
├── minimatch@3.0.0 (brace-expansion@1.1.1)
├── expand-braces@0.1.2 (array-unique@0.2.1, array-slice@0.2.3, braces@0.1.5)
├── glob@5.0.15 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, once@1.3.2, inflight@1.0.4)
├── log4js@0.6.27 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, semver@4.3.6, readable-stream@1.0.33)
├── dom-serialize@2.2.1 (custom-event@1.0.0, void-elements@2.0.1, ent@2.2.0, extend@3.0.0)
├── core-js@1.2.6
├── connect@3.4.0 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, debug@2.2.0, finalhandler@0.4.0)
├── body-parser@1.14.1 (bytes@2.1.0, content-type@1.0.1, depd@1.1.0, on-finished@2.3.0, raw-body@2.1.4, qs@5.1.0, debug@2.2.0, iconv-lite@0.4.12, http-errors@1.3.1, type-is@1.6.9)
├── chokidar@1.2.0 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, arrify@1.0.0, glob-parent@2.0.0, async-each@0.1.6, is-binary-path@1.0.1, is-glob@2.0.1, lodash.flatten@3.0.2, readdirp@2.0.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
└── socket.io@1.3.7 (has-binary-data@0.1.3, debug@2.1.0, socket.io-adapter@0.3.1, socket.io-parser@2.2.4, engine.io@1.5.4, socket.io-client@1.3.7)
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to troubleshoot this?

Any suggestion /insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and I solved by doing the following:

1. ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. went to my project directory
3. ran the following commands

   ```
    npm config set strict-ssl false
    npm install karma --save-dev
   ```
4. ```
   npm install karma-jasmine karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev
   ```